# Open a file, search for a string and fill a string in another file

Tags: perl, file

I have 2 text files. I"m writing a perl script wherein i need to find "Unable to parse" string in a text file and then extract the whole line having this string. Extract part of this string after "/" and store the string in a variable.

Then i need to open the other text file, find the stored string in this text file and replace the string.

```
    my $ldir = "/Android";
    $RESULTS_FILE = $ldir.'/'.'results.html';
    open OUT, ">>", $RESULTS_FILE;
    open(IN,"<logcat.txt");

    while(<IN>)
    {
            chomp;
            if( $_ =~ m/Unable to parse/ )
            {
                    my @string = split('/',$_);
                    print @string;
                    my $stream_name = $string[4];
                    while $srch(<OUT>)
                    {
                            chomp;
                            if( $srch =~ m/$stream_name/ )
                            {
                                  // How to replace the line here?
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

Please help.

Regards,
Ramki

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file, replace all occurances of your target string with something, then save that file back out again:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

sub replace_string_in_file {
    my ( $source, $target, $filename ) = @_;

    my $filecontents = do {
            open my $fd, "<" $filename;
            local $/;
            <$fd>;
    };

    $filecontents =~ s/$source/$target/mg;

    open my $fd, ">", $filename;
    print $fd $filecontents;
    close($fd);
}

my $ldir = "/Android";
$RESULTS_FILE = $ldir.'/'.'results.html';
open(IN,"<logcat.txt");

while(<IN>)
{
        chomp;
        if( $_ =~ m/Unable to parse/ )
        {
                my @string = split('/',$_);
                print @string;
                my $stream_name = $string[4];

            replace_string_in_file( $stream_name, "THIS IS THE REPLACEMENT", $RESULTS_FILE );
        }
}
```